# Pi value for Circle a

Tags: trigonometry

IF I Have **Pi value** For Circle that mean i have the ***Ratio between The Circumference and Diameter*** [by def.]

I noted in lesson of Measuring angles By The Radian Also **Pi Value** ***which standards for 180 degree***
What is The Different between The **First Pi** and the **Second Pi** ? are They Related to each other ?

Comment: It's the same number.

Comment: How that Can Be ?

Comment: @AmmarBamhdi Do you mean the numerical value or the meaning of $\pi$ in both contexts ?

Comment: meaning of π in both contexts @Peter

Comment: In this case, the meanings are closely related because the radians is nothing else than the arc length in a unit circle (a circle with radius $1$) , namely the length of a part of the circle which is covered by an angle. Note that the complete unit circle has arc length $2\pi$, so $180$° (half circle) corresponds with $\pi$

Comment: There are 2pi radians in 360 degrees. This is about 57.3 deg. per radian. When you divide the circumference of a circle by its radius, it comes out to 2pi, hence an arc of length one radius, subtends an angle of one radian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me define what a radian is:

Suppose you have a circle radius $r$. If you measure an angle of $k^c$ ($k$ radians) from the centre, the portion of the circle's edge between the two lines that form your angle will have length $kr$.

Note that $\pi^c=180^0$, thus $2\pi^c=360^0$. 
So if theoretically you stated that the two radii you were creating the angle between were the same line (i.e. the angle between them was the whole way around the circle - either $360^0$ or $2\pi^c$), the arc created would have length $2\pi r$. This is also the circumference by the way I measured it from the same line, so 
$$c=2\pi r\therefore c=\pi d \therefore\pi=\frac{c}{d}$$
Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

$\pi$ is the number which represents the ratio of the circumference to the diameter, so a circle of radius $r$ has circumference $2\pi r$.  In radian measure, a central angle is measured by the ratio of the length of the arc it subtends to the radius of the circle.  So, in a circle of radius $r$ a central angle of $180^{\circ}$ subtends an arc of length $\pi r$ and the radian measure is $$\frac{\pi r}{r}=\pi$$